# PHP Change JSON format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to change the below JSON Data to my own format.

**From this :**

```
[
      [
            {
                  "venue" : "ABC Room",
                  "date" : "20191014",
                  "staff_name" : "Adam",
                  "age" : 30,
            },
            {
                 "venue" : "ABC Room",
                  "date" : "20191014",
                  "staff_name" : "Mia",
                  "age" : 35,
            },
            {     "venue" : "DEF Room",
                  "date" : "20191010",
                  "staff_name" : "Sofia",
                  "age" : "36",
            }
      ],
      [     {     
                  "ph_year":"2019",
                  "ph_date":"20190205",
                  "ph_statecode":"ALL",
                  "ph_event":"02",
                  "ph_type":"01"
            }
      ]
]
```

**Change to :**

```
[
    {
        "venue" : "ABC Room",
        "date" : "20191014",
        "staff": {
            "staff": [
                {
                    "staff_name" : "Adam",
                    "age" : 30,
                },
                {
                    "staff_name" : "Mia",
                    "age" : 35,
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "venue" : "DEF Room",
        "date" : "20191010",
        "staff": {
            "staff": [
                {
                    "staff_name" : "Sofia",
                    "age" : "36",
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "publicholiday": {
            "ph_date": "20190205",
            "phevent": "02"
        }
    }
]
```

Please someone help me..Can someone give me the idea or method to this? How to call it in foreach function? I already try before, but not successful.Any help is much appreciated!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: This has nothing to deal with Laravel, it's PHP. And you ask for something really specific, I don't know what you expect from SO but your script is too long and too specific

Comment: thank you very much for your comment @VincentDecaux ..i already edit my answer..

Comment: Answer? Or Question?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Question..@Rahul

Comment: Noted..Thank you for your comment..@JayBlanchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet,

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $element) {
    foreach ($element as $value) {
        if (!empty($value['venue'])) {
            $result[$value['venue']]['venue']            = $value['venue'];
            $result[$value['venue']]['date']             = $value['date'];
            $result[$value['venue']]['staff']['staff'][] = $value;
        } else {
            $result["publicholiday"]['ph_date'] = $value['ph_date'];
            $result["publicholiday"]['phevent'] = $value['ph_event'];
        }
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oJQ5J)

**Output:-**

```
[
    {
        "venue": "ABC Room",
        "date": "20191014",
        "staff": {
            "staff": [
                {
                    "venue": "ABC Room",
                    "date": "20191014",
                    "staff_name": "Adam",
                    "age": 30
                },
                {
                    "venue": "ABC Room",
                    "date": "20191014",
                    "staff_name": "Mia",
                    "age": 35
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "venue": "DEF Room",
        "date": "20191010",
        "staff": {
            "staff": [
                {
                    "venue": "DEF Room",
                    "date": "20191010",
                    "staff_name": "Sofia",
                    "age": "36"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "ph_date": "20190205",
        "phevent": "02"
    }
]
```